# MySQL -Locate SQL Query on Pinned Tabs

Tags: mysql

I know when using SQL Developer on the query tab there was a 'SQL' link you could click on to show the query for that tab and from there you could copy that query if you wanted.  This was good because you could clear the query in the typing field and always be able to go to any of your pinned tabs and in each tab you could grab the query that's stored for that search.

Is there a way to find your SQL query on tabs in MySQL? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What GUI are you using - mysql workbench, heidisql or something else?

Comment: Oh, sorry i didn't specify.  I'm using MySQL workbench, thank you.